# Rails localhost not working errno:eaccess

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

Sorry for dumb question. I'm newbie. I try to reopen my saved page but rails server not working. Here's the conflict. Really glad for your help. Thank you.

```
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:4:in `require': Permission denied @ io_fillbuf - fd:3 c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/source_annotation_extractor.rb (Errno::EACCES)
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.1/lib/sprockets/railtie.rb:18:in `require'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.1/lib/sprockets/railtie.rb:18:in `<class:Application>'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.1/lib/sprockets/railtie.rb:15:in `<module:Rails>'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.1/lib/sprockets/railtie.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/all.rb:14:in `require'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/all.rb:14:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/all.rb:12:in `each'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/all.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
        from c:/Sites/yelpdemo/config/application.rb:3:in `require'
        from c:/Sites/yelpdemo/config/application.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:133:in `require'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:133:in `block in perform'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:130:in `tap'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:130:in `perform'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/command/base.rb:63:in `perform'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/command.rb:44:in `invoke'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you use [The Rails Installer](http://railsinstaller.org/en) by any chance? I have never gotten that to one click install Rails to work on a windows machine before.

Instead I would follow the steps outlined in [this tutorial](https://gorails.com/setup/windows/10).